# Best practices for implementing clean/maintainable Android layouts

Tags: android, layout

What is the best way to structure a layout that is not trivially simple so that it doesn't get very messy and unmaintainable.

So far this is what I am doing:

- Declare styles and apply them to common elements in the view instead of setting attributes manually on each element.
- Separate out common rich layout groups and use the `<include />` tag to reuse them. http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Something I haven't looked at yet is Fragments.  But I would appreciate some tips around how to make layouts cleaner.

Also, how to you manage with having to reference all these layout views in the activity class in a clean way?  I have been declaring these getter methods (see example below) so that all the methods that needed to use these aren't riddled with the code of getting a reference to them.

```
private TextView getErrorTextView() {
    return (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helloTextView);
}
```

and then where i need to use them I can do

```
getErrorTextView().setText(...);
```

Comment: `findViewById` is very expensive, invoking it every time you need a reference will seriously hurt your app performance

Comment: @dtmilano thanks for the tip, I didn't know that.  I guess I should have an init() method then and get a reference to them all once at the start?

Answer (score 0):

1. Fragments: May or may not solve your problem. You get reusable fully functional pieces of UI, but you can run into trouble managing life-cycle of all those fragment.
2. Finding Views can be replaced by frameworks that inject views, such as: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Comment: Thanks @S.D. I am using RoboGuice for that now https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice